# Overall CPU utilization is over the threshold in IIS 7.5

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, cpu-usage, w3wp.exe

Since so many days we are facing a problem for 100% CPU utilization. 
Tried monitoring in multiple ways using IIS logs, procdump, DebugDial and performance monitoring. By these analysis received some requests which taking time but after looking into code seems there is no problem in code too.

Server has McCafe antivirus installed on it and no other things.

Can you please guide how to track this? or is there any configuration of server which causing this problem?

Comment: Did you check your memory utilization? If you are hitting the memory ceiling, you may be experiencing thrashing. If you allow virtual memory using disk, you may also be thrashing to disk.

Comment: Hi Taylor, we have looked into memory and observed that Garbage collection taking more memory. Started optimizing respective code for this.